# ionic: on-release event is triggered before releasing touch

Tags: android, html, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I am using ionic to build a mobile app.

I am facing a serious issue.

I have to use on-touch and on-release events but issue is whenever I touch, on-release even is also fired instantly without releasing in actual.

I have struggled alot, researched online but I did not find any solution for that.

These events works perfectly in iOS but it is behaving like this in android only.

I'll really appreciate any contribution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed my issue.
Just install this plugin [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview](https://github.com/phonegap-build/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) and issue will be resolved.

Comment: ionic browser add crosswalk@12.41.296.5 fixed for me